# Joining nested associations, group and order by count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested model structure:

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :forum

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :post_links
  has_many :links, ->{ uniq }, through: :post_links, dependent: :destroy

class PostLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :link

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_links
  has_many :posts, ->{ uniq }, through: :post_links, dependent: :destroy
```

So I want to get all link that are in posts that are in topics that are in forum with id = 1

And sort them descending by number of occurences in this forum.

So if I have `youtube.com` 5 times in some posts in forum with id = 1, and 10 time `google.com` then I'd like to have something like:

```
id,name,mentions_count
1,google.com,10
2,youtube.com,5
```

Comment: Count of link mentions in all posts in this forum.

Comment: Order posts in forum 1 by their links count?

Comment: I edited my qustion to be more precise with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Forum.where(id: 1).joins(topics: [posts: [:links]]).order("count_all DESC").group("links.host").count 
=>  {"youtube.com"=>5, "google.com"=>2}
```

I assumed that you have host column in your links table